# Is it possible to convert java into java script via some online tool?

Tags: javascript, java

This piece of java code needs to be converted to javascript ?

```
private void validatePartitionSum() throws ProfileUsageException {
    int moSize = maxSizeMO == -1 ? 0 : maxSizeMO;
    int mtSize = maxSizeMT == -1 ? 0 : maxSizeMT;
    if (maxSize > 0 && moSize + mtSize > maxSize) {
      //added to default limit type to Messages when error occurs
      if(this.editPartitionLimitFlag == false) {
      this.limitType = ThresholdType.MESSAGES;
      }
      String errorMessage =
        getFormattedResourceValue(STORAGE_SUM_LARGER_THAN_TOTAL);
      throw new ProfileUsageException(errorMessage,
          MMException.INVALID_PARAMETER);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This does not compile in java, any solution in javascript will not work aswell :D

Comment: Hi Ritika. Good luck with the translation. I don't think this is the purpose of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

look into gwt, (not online tool)

quote: "Write browser applications in Java using the Java IDE of your choice"

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html

http://www.gwtproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Google Web Toolkit](http://www.gwtproject.org/)